# When does mapquest route finish rendering?

Tags: leaflet, mapquest

I am using MapQuest map with leaflet. The routes are being injected dynamically. When we add routes to the map, it takes time to finish the rendering.
I want to block the screen while the map is being rendered.
Is there any way(mapquest API or leaflet event) to know the map is ready or finished rendering so that I can stop the blocking of the screen.

I'm using Leaflet to add the routes. Something like this:

```
function (locations) {
  const dir = MQ.routing.directions();
  dir.route({ locations: locations });
  comp.mqroute = MQ.routing.routeLayer({
    directions: dir,
    fitBounds: true,
    draggable: false,
  });
  comp.map.addLayer(comp.mqroute);
}
```

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you want to block the screen in the first place?

Comment: Also, it'd be nice to know how you are requesting the routes. Any library? Leaflet plugin? Manual `fetch` requests?

Comment: 1. As I mentioned earlier, the map is taking time to plot the routes, I want to prevent the user from clicking any other buttons on the screen.
2. I'm using Leaflet to add the routes. Something like this: 
function (locations) {
            const dir = MQ.routing.directions();
            dir.route({
                locations: locations
            });
            comp.mqroute = MQ.routing.routeLayer({
                directions: dir,
                fitBounds: true,
                draggable: false,
            });
            comp.map.addLayer(comp.mqroute);
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case of RTFM.

The fact that you're using `MQ.routing.directions` in your code tells me that you're using the [Mapquest routing plugin for Leaflet](https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/leaflet-plugins/routing/), which has [complete API documentation](https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/leaflet-plugins/routing/).

By reading that API documentation, one can notice a `success` event, I quote:

> `success`
>
> Fired when route data has been retrieved from the server and shapePoints have been decompressed. [...]

I have a heavy suspicion that you don't need to know when the route is *rendered* (meaning: when the lines have been displayed on the screen) but rather when then *network requests for the route are finished* (which is what takes most time). The time to actually render lines on the screen is usually negligible unless one is working with thousands of segments (after the automatic douglas-peucker simplification).

I also have a heavy suspicion that this is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and that the root problem you're trying to solve is race conditions when the user is (re-)requesting routes too fast, to which the solution is just throttling the requests rather than blocking the UI.

How to use this `success` event is illustrated in MapQuest's [Route Narrative example](https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/leaflet-plugins/routing/#narrative):

```
dir = MQ.routing.directions();

dir.on('success', function(data) {
     // ...
     // the code here will run once the route is ready
     // ...
  }
```